# Subtract 2 datagridview grouped columns to third column

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

This is a datagridview I'm using to show the stock of products, I was able to make it populate with a group by barcode and productname and sum of Purchase, sum of sales

now what i'm trying to do is to subtract sales from purchases and show in a third column

here is the code I tried

```
private void frmStock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User Id=;Password=;Data Source=TS-POS.accdb");
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Bcode, Pname, SUM(Ppurchase) AS Ppurchase, SUM(Psale) AS Psale FROM Stock GROUP BY Bcode,Pname;", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    conn.Close();
    Update();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Update();

}
private void update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

        int c = a - b;

        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = c;


    }
}
```

Problem now is, it will not show anything at all

Comment: see the update to my answer based on your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting that you have this in a form_load event. Is that correct? The reason I believe this to be true is that your connectionstring is not correct for the database you're using and should be throwing an exception. The Load event doesn't show the exception unless you wrap the offending code into a try...catch block. The .accdb extension uses the Microsoft.ACE provider.

I'm not sure how you're getting anything at all as you shouldn't even be able to access that version with your current provider. I can only go by what you are telling me and must assume that the data you're seeing is coming from some other code.

Here is a typical connectionstring for your .accdb database residing in my documents folder.

```
Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\Charlie\Documents\TS-POS.accdb
```

EDIT DUE TO CHANGES MADE TO THE QUESTION

Rename the update() method. Update is a keyword. Notice that your sub is called update but your trying to call Update? (C# is case-sensitive)

Also, you can do this math in the sqlstatement

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Bcode, Pname, SUM(Ppurchase) AS Ppurchase, SUM(Psale) AS Psale, SUM(Ppurchase) - SUM(Psale) as Total FROM Stock GROUP BY Bcode,Pname;", conn);
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, i already solved this problem, you answered while I was updating with the last issue i currently have, please recheck the question

Comment: Thanks Again Charles but unfortunately that didn't work as well

Comment: I'm going to need a little more than that from you. Stating that didn't work after offering 2 suggestions doesn't give me much to go on. The Update method will error because I see nowhere where you add a 4th column for this new information to hold. The query changes should work as long as the query works and would be a better method since it will be a part of the dataset automatically.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the column through the design view, I tried the SQL calculation first, no rows showed up, I added a comma after the second sum, it showed all rows but didn't make calculation, I tried changing the AS Total to the column name with no luck.
As for the update, I changed the name to calc, and made sure it was called in the correct lettercase, but still no luck. it shows the datagrid rows but will not display calculation in that 5th row

Comment: OK, as a test add another DataGridView to your form (dataGridView2). Make it wide enough to show your expected data. Make sure your code runs my query that I provided in the bottom of my answer. Add `dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` right above your `conn.Close();` line. Run and show me a screenshot of the result of both datagridviews.

Comment: Weirdly enough it worked on the second dataGridView perfectly, and didn't work on the first one. Thank you so much, Charles, been trying to do this for the past 12 hours, now is there a way I can change the header of these Columns? or am I stuck with them?

Comment: That's why I had you do it, sometimes you start trying things and never get everything back to normal and then it just appears nothing works. As far as the headers, they are what you use in the AS clause of your query. So you could essentially say ` "SELECT Bcode AS [Bar Code] ... ` notice I used the [ ] when I wanted to use a space.

Comment: Unfortunately I try that but it doesn't work with Arabic letters

Comment: You might try setting them via the HeaderText property.  `dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "your header label";` I would think that would allow Arabic. Just do it after you fill it from the dataset. And you will have to repeat for columns[1], [2], etc...